# Alternative to strcmp() to alphabetically sort strings

Tags: c++

stuType Class:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>

using namespace std;

#ifndef STUTYPE
#define STUTYPE

class stuType {

   private:

   string fname;
   string lname;
   string social;
   float gpa;

   public:

      stuType(void) {

         fname = "no_fname";
         lname = "no_lname";
         social = "no_social";
         gpa = 0.0;
      }

      stuType(string fname_in, string lname_in, string social_in, float gpa_in) {

         fname = fname_in;
         lname = lname_in;
         social = social_in;
         gpa = gpa_in;
      }

     ~stuType() {
        //Nothing needs to be added here.
     }

     void set_fname(string new_fname) {
        fname = new_fname;
     }

     void set_lname(string new_lname) {
        lname = new_lname;
     }

     void set_ssn(string new_ssn) {
        social = new_ssn;
     }

     void set_gpa(float new_gpa) {
        gpa = new_gpa;
     }

     string get_fname(void) {
        return fname;
     }

     string get_lname(void) {
        return lname;
     }

     string get_ssn(void) {
        return social;
     }

     float get_gpa(void) {
        return gpa;
     }

     friend istream & operator>>(istream &in, stuType &stu) {
        in>>stu.fname;
        in>>stu.lname;
        in>>stu.social;
        in>>stu.gpa;

        return in;
     }

};

#endif
```

Sort.cpp:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<cstring>

#include"stuType.h"

using namespace std;

/*Loads the elements of the object instance with data from the input file.*/
void load(istream &input, stuType Student[], int *size);

/*Used in combination with the shellSort method to exchange the values of two variables in the class object.*/
void exchange(stuType &a, stuType &b);

/*Sorts the objects in ascending order by comparing the values of the lname strings between object indices.*/
void shellSort(stuType Student[], int size);

int main() {

   stuType Student[10];

   int size;

   char inputFile[200];
   char outputFile[200];

   ifstream input;
   ofstream output;

   cout<<"[INPUT_FILE]: ";
   cin>>inputFile;

   cout<<"[OUTPUT_FILE]: ";
   cin>>outputFile;

   input.open(inputFile);
   output.open(outputFile);

   if (input.fail()) {
      cerr<<"\n[FILE] Error opening '"<<inputFile<<"'"<<endl;
      exit(1);
   }

   if (output.fail()) {
      cerr<<"\n[FILE] Error opening '"<<outputFile<<"'"<<endl;
      exit(1);
   }

   load(input, Student, &size);
   shellSort(Student, size);

   return 0;
}

void load(istream &input, stuType Student[], int *size) {

   int length = 0, i = 0;

   float gpa;
   string social;
   string fname;
   string lname;

   while(input >> social >> fname >> lname >> gpa) {
      cout<<"[Node::Load] Setting 'social' for index ["<<i<<"] to "<<social<<endl;
      Student[i].set_ssn(social);
      cout<<"[Node::Load] Setting 'fname' for index ["<<i<<"] to "<<fname<<endl; 
      Student[i].set_fname(fname);
      cout<<"[Node::Load] Setting 'lname' for index ["<<i<<"] to "<<lname<<endl;
      Student[i].set_lname(lname);
      cout<<"[Node::Load] Setting 'gpa' for index ["<<i<<"] to "<<gpa<<endl;
      Student[i].set_gpa(gpa);
      cout<<"[Node::Load] Incrementing 'length'..."<<endl;
      length++;
      cout<<"[Node::Load] Incrementing 'i'..."<<endl;
      i++;
   }

   cout<<"==================================="<<endl;
   for (int i = 0; i<length; i++) {
      cout<<"[ENTRY] Index: "<<i<<" | SSN: "<<Student[i].get_ssn()<<" | fname: "<<Student[i].get_fname()<<" | lname: "<<Student[i].get_lname()<<" | gpa: "<<Student[i].get_gpa()<<endl;
   }
   cout<<"==================================="<<endl;

   *size = length;
}

void exchange(stuType &a, stuType &b) {

   stuType *temp;

   *temp = a;
   a = b;
   b = *temp;

   delete temp;
}

void shellSort(stuType Student[], int size) {

   int gap = size/2;
   bool passOK;

   while(gap>0) {
      passOK = true;

      for(int i = 0; i<size-gap; i++) {
            if (strcmp(Student[i].get_lname(), Student[i+gap].get_lname)>0) {
               cout<<"[Node::Sort] Exchanging Index ["<<i<<"] with Index ["<<i+gap<<"]..."<<endl;
               exchange(Student[i], Student[i+gap]);
               passOK = false;
            } else if (strcmp(Student[i].get_lname(), Student[i+gap].get_lname())==0) {
               if (strcmp(Student[i].get_fname(), Student[i+gap].get_fname())>0) {
                  cout<<"[Node::Sort] Exchanging Index ["<<i<<"] with Index ["<<i+gap<<"]..."<<endl;
                  exchange(Student[i], Student[i+gap]);
                  passOK = false;
                }
            }
        }

        if (passOK) {
            gap /= 2;
        }
    }
}
```

strcmp() expects to receive a character array to do the comparison, but since I am using strings, I cannot do that. What is an alternative? The variable 'lname' needs to be compared and should return true if Student[i].get_lname() is greater than Student[i+gap].get_lname(). The exchange function will then be called and exchange the values of the object's local variables. The objects should be sorted in ascending order based on the value of the 'lname' variable and the 'fname' variable should only be referenced if the two 'lname's being compared are the same.

Comment: strcmp needs to be used for arrays because comparing arrays with < or = just compares the memory location and not the content.  std::string overrides < and = to do something useful so you can just use < or = for comparison.

Comment: Your setters that take a string argument should take a `const string &` not a copy of a string.  You defined an input operator for reading students; why don't you use it?  Your `exchange` function is rather heavyweight, isn't it (at least compared with `{ string t = a; a = b; b = t; }`, and that's not using C++11 `swap` technology — `std::swap(a, b)`)?

Answer (score 1):

C++ strings provide [implementations of operators `<` and `>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp), so you can use them instead of `strcmp`:

```
std::string a = "hello";
std::string b = "world";
if (a < b) {
    cout << a << " is less than " << b << endl;
}
```

Comment: So if I were to refrain from using strcmp() entirely and just compare the two strings using < > or == then it will order them alphabetically?

Comment: @AdamChubbuck, Lexicographically, actually, but close enough.

Comment: @AdamChubbuck `<` and `>` compare strings lexicographically, in a case-sensitive way. Due to the way the upper and lower case characters are represented in ASCII, any uppercase character would sort ahead of a lowercase character (e.g. `Z` < `a`).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight So assuming that the data file passed to the program contains names that are capitalized properly (following proper capitalization rules), I should have no problem? Consider the following: String #1: "Low" ; String #2: "Arme" - when compared, String #1 will be considered a higher value than String #2?

Comment: @AdamChubbuck This is very easy to test - [check this out](http://ideone.com/XIqi7Z).

Comment: @AdamChubbuck You are welcome! If you find the answer helpful, please accept it by clicking the grey check mark next to it.